# Ubuntu booting screen missing in 15.04 desktop

Tags: boot, 15.04, plymouth

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 using Unetbootin. (dual boot with windows 7).
 But on booting Ubuntu I get a pink screen (same color as grub default background)  which changes to black after a few seconds (not a gradual transition) and then after about 10 seconds (average boot time) the Ubuntu login screen shows up and then everything is normal. No Ubuntu boot animation is shown. Everything else works. How do I fix this?
grub file as requested by community 
`/etc/default/grub` :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1360x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Note:

```
I was having this problem since the first boot.
I am using default graphic driver
```

Comment: dual boot with windows 7

Comment: No i can boot into windows just fine. And even Ubuntu works. but the splash screen never shows up.

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/621059/edit) button to add information to your post.

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` to your answer. Also are you seeing anything written on the pink screen?

Comment: no i am not getting anything written on pink screen

Comment: will pressing f8 during boot help knowing what is happening?

Comment: i dont think you guys understand. Grub is shown. The boot animation isnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot into GRUB by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. In GRUB press <kbd>C</kbd> to open a command line
3. Start the command `vbeinfo` to see all resolutions, eg. `1920x1200x32`
4. Reboot your system
5. Open the file `/etc/default/grub`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   and add or change the line

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=<your_resolution>
   ```

   eg:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x32
   ```

   now add or change the line

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
   ```
6. Save the configuration and start the command

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep , just below  GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x32?

Comment: yes, it's ok. =)

Comment: i think you mean 'c'

Comment: nope still the same

Comment: Which graphic, Nvidia or Ati?

Comment: nvidia geforce 410m

Comment: i previously had 14.04 but i used os uninstaller and then installed ubuntu 15.04 from a live usb (made using unetbootin). It was booting fine in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I think you should install the proprietary Nvidia driver. Your model is supported since version 275.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't fix it this is depends on your graphics card driver the default have normal ubuntu animation and if you change the driver the boot maybe look diferent (i was changed my and is displaying only Ubuntu 14.04 text and blinking dots). If you have the default one maybe somewhere is a problem try install Super Boot Manager and change Plymouth.

Comment: go to  http://askubuntu.com/questions/590222/ubuntu-14-04-boot-animation-is-different-lower-graphics-after-using-nvidia-gra . i had the same problem in 14.04 . use vbeinfo in real grub to see supported resolutions.

Comment: It is a known issue with some Nvidia cards. I also have the problem with my AMD R9 290. You can try switching drivers in 'Additional drivers' and see if you can fix is that way. If it doesn't work and it's irritating you, it might be an idea to lower the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` and  `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=`. Also see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210008